# Python: How to use an method from another class

Tags: python

I came across a situation similar to this, my goal is to use a method from an object that does not have access to attr that belongs to the object from which it was obtained.

In the example, there is a class `A` that inherits the `_request` method of class `C`, which can only be used from `A` because only in `A` there is the `token` attribute.

In addition, `A` contains a method that returns an object of `B`: `get_b_obj`.

And here's the question: `B` has a method (`change_name`) that wants to access the network by using `C`'s `_request` using `A` that contains the `token` attr. How do I use `_request` without getting AtributeError?

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_request'
```

I hope the question is understood, I could not attach the original code :(

FILE_1.py: the main class, can use self._request from C

```
from FILE_2 import C
from FILE_3 import B

class A(C):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def update_something(self): # this work's because A has self.token attr
        self._request(body={'to_update': 'something'})

    def get_b_obj(self, name):
    return B(name)
```

FILE_2.py: the request class, works only within A (because self.token).

```
import requests

class C:
    def _request(self, body=None):
        headers = {'token': self.token}
        requests.get('https://example.com', headers=headers, json=body)
```

FILE_3.py: the object that want to use C._request() method

```
from FILE_2 import _C # ?

class B:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def change_name(self, new_name):
        self._request(body={'new_name': new_name})  # here is the question
```

CODE:

```
main_obj = A(token="ABC123")
new_b = main_obj.get_b_obj("name")
new_b.change_name("new_name")

# AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_request'
```

Comment: Can't you have B inherit of A? From what I understand, you need the token in B to use A's function, so having B inherit of A would make sense, you would just need to change `__init__` a bit

Comment: You could pass `self` as an additional parameter to `B` when you create an instance, that it would store in an instance attribute, and use to invoke `._request()` on when needed.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your answer! I actually thought about that, but I try to avoid it because there are several classes similar to ``B`` and I do not want every time I create their instance out of ``A``, to provide the self so they can use ``_request``. There is no other option? global shared instance of A or something like this..?

Comment: Make `_request` a module level function, maybe with a `token` parameter.

Comment: @Gugu72 @wwii In both solutions, I will have to provide the token whenever I want to use ``_request``.
I want to provide it once when I create instance of ``A`` and then use ``_request`` from anywhere possible.

(In the original code I actually do not provide a token but a username and password, then at the  A init I use ``_request`` to get a token and assign it to the ``token`` attr)

Comment: Why does `C._request()` use an attribute `token` that doesn't exist in `C`? That seems like broken design unless C is an abstract base class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hint: you know how the built-in `str` type has a `.replace` method? Notice how you are not able to call `self.replace` on any of your classes, either? Why do you suppose that is? "the request class, works only within A (because self.token)." No, it works because `class A(C):`.  Look closely at the error message. Notice how it says something about `_request`? Notice how it does **not** say anything about `token`?

Comment: Actually, I should ask a pop quiz first, because I think you fundamentally misunderstand some things, in a way that makes it impossible to give a clear answer yet. In your own words, what is a class? What is the purpose of a class? When you write `class C:`, what does that **do**?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The separation between C and A is for reasons of order only. Indeed, ``_request`` should have been in A.  The main question was how to use it without passing the instance of A whenever I still want to use it from the outside.

Comment: @Barmar, ``token`` is not exists in C because it is not supposed to work separately (A and C are separated for reasons of order only), only by A where ``token`` exists. I know it does not make the most sense, but I have seen a number of libraries that work this way .. The Class C just should not work separately..

Comment: If C can't be instantiated by itself, that's the definition of an abstract base class.

Comment: "The separation between C and A is for reasons of order only. Indeed, _request should have been in A. The main question was how to use it without passing the instance of A whenever I still want to use it from the outside." None of this answers my questions. I can't make any sense out of the code because a) the way that the classes are related to each other isn't normal and b) since there are no class names and no description of *what the classes are intended to represent*, I can't begin to guess **why** you want the classes to work like this (or even why all three of them exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B` should have an attribute that links back to the object that created it.

```
class A(C):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def update_something(self): # this work's because A has self.token attr
        self._request(body={'to_update': 'something'})

    def get_b_obj(self, name):
        return B(name, self)

class B:
    def __init__(self, name, creator):
        self.name = name
        self.creator = creator

    def change_name(self, new_name):
        self.creator._request(body={'new_name': new_name})
```